# conky netstat monitor that ignores localhost

Tags: conky

I have a conky script that includes the tcp_monitor, but it shows all the localhost connections, too. (::1 and 127.0.0.1)

I cannot split the display by port numbers, as most conky configs do, so I need to filter out localhost.

Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having just received the 'Tumbleweed' badge for this question, I think I will answer it with an alternate configuration in case it helps someone:

```
${execp netstat -upant | grep "tcp\|udp" | grep -v "127.0.0.1\|::1" | awk '{split($4, a, ":"); print "%s %s\n", a[1], a[2] }' }
```

From this starting place, I can grep for different states, different IPs, etc. It's not as good as tcp_monitor and it eats more resources, but it works for my needs.